# How to avoid a duplicated Android list (main menu)

Tags: android, list, menu, duplicates, listactivity

I've a simple application that lists items (using a simpleAdapter list) from sqlite database. But, every time, i open the application it displays the list in a duplicated fashion. If i reopen it again, it'll duplicate the lists once again. The same is true for the sub menus (lists).

What should i do? I tried to use the onDestroy() method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   //Log.d(APP_NAME, "APPLICATION onTerminate");
   Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is getting killed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but, it's not avoiding the duplicates. Is there anyway to clear the list every time i move to another activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the list inside this activity's onResume method. It will clear the list every time you get back to your activity. Hope this helps.